# g sensor(accelerometer) curve on HTC One M8

Tags: android, accelerometer

I used to extract accelerometer data by android SDK on Samsung Galaxy S4,
and I encounter a strange problem when I change platform to HTC One M8.

Here is the statement about the experiment:
Once I move the device from place A to place B straight(negative direction of device), I will read the accelerometer data and compute the displacement between A and B.
The curve of acceleromter data on S4 is correct.
It contains two pick with different sign and the shape like 'S' lie on the floor.

But when I use M8, it give me the curve which is wrong obviously. it looks like 'W'
P.S. The motion and program of two are totally the same.

Can anyone give me some reason to the difference? 
Is the g-sensor on M8 is the problem?
I'm really stuck on it.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from trying to use the Moves app, this is due to lack of support of the accelerometer when the device's display is off.

I am looking for a way to change that now and if I find something I will update here.

update:

It seems this could just be due to new hardware not being supported yet. This quote leads me to believe that "...are the low-powered, always listening "Smart Sensors." Accelerometers are nothing new, but HTC's can be used by apps all day long without significant drain on the the battery (as they don't fire up the processor etc). As HTC's opened up the API for these -- dubbed HTC's Smart Sensor Hub -- app developers will be able to hook into this information directly."